# "No Results" When No face shows up (Swift) -Simple

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, boolean, wikipedia

I have made an app where you type in the someone well-known and their face is pulled from wikipedia. Yes, everything works fine when you type in a name that has a wikipedia page. But if you type in something else that has no results, I need there to be something that says "No results". My code is below but the "No results" is never called, even when there are no results.

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    realLoadingLbl.alpha = 1

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
  faceImageView.alpha = 0


    self.realLoadingLbl.text = "Loading...Trying to Grab Photo..."



    if timerRunning == false{
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: ("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerRunning = true
    }





    if let textFieldContent = textField.text{
        do {
            try WikiFaceRec.faceForPerson(textFieldContent, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 250), completion: {(image:UIImage?, imageFound:Bool!) -> ()  in
                if imageFound == true{
                    self.timerCount = 6
                    self.timerRunning = false
                   self.realLoadingLbl.alpha = 0
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                        self.faceImageView.image = image
                        self.faceImageView.alpha = 1
                        WikiFaceRec.centerImageViewOnFace(self.faceImageView)
                    })
                    if imageFound == false{
                        self.faceImageView.alpha = 0
                        self.realLoadingLbl.text = "No Results Found. Check your spelling and try again."
                        print("NO RESULTS")

                    }
                }
        })
        }catch WikiFaceRec.WikiFaceError.CouldNotDownloadImage{
        print("Wikipedia not currently open")
        }catch{
            print("error")
            self.faceImageView.alpha = 0
            self.realLoadingLbl.text = "No Results Found. Check your spelling and try again."
            print("NO RESULTS")
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Set some breakpoints and see what your program is actually doing when it can't load an image. You currently have 2 areas with "NO RESULTS" . Unless you can provide more information, we might need to see what "faceForPerson" actually does.

Comment: imageFOund == false is never called.

Comment: Then that Bool is always true. Maybe check the image instead? It's an optional, so if it comes back empty then there is no image. There's like 3 levels of error checking here. You have a try/catch, which I'm assuming throws an error if no image is returned, then you have the Bool, AND UIImage can also be checked. Does that make sense?

Comment: On y FaceRecognition class, it does say imageFound = false with no image

Comment: Oh man. I think you have that other if statement embedded in the previous if statement

Comment: Check your curly braces, and see the indentation?

Comment: Given the answer, can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_.

Comment: @halfer this was more than a year ago...

Comment: @Andy: ah, if you are not aware: we want to look after all 15 million questions on this site, which includes editing, voting, closing and deleting, regardless of age. If you are in agreement that this can be closed under the stated reason, there may be a widget above that allows you to do that (the community can, but it's quicker if you do it). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have your `if imageFound = false` statement inside your `if imageFound = true` statement.